# How to pipe commands using Ansible? e.g. curl -sL host.com | sudo bash -

Tags: ansible, pipe

I want to make the command via Ansible:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
```

How can I do it via Ansible? Now I have:

```
- name: Add repository
  command: curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
```

But it throw error:

```
[WARNING]: Consider using get_url or uri module rather than running curl
```

`fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["curl", "-sL", "https://deb.nodesource.com/setup", "|", "sudo", "bash", "-"], "delta": "0:00:00.006202", "end": "2017-12-27 15:11:55.441754", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2017-12-27 15:11:55.435552", "stderr": "curl: option -: is unknown\ncurl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information", "stderr_lines": ["curl: option -: is unknown", "curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ansible wget then exec scripts => get\_url equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965199/ansible-wget-then-exec-scripts-get-url-equivalent)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can:

```
- name: Add repository
  shell: curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
  args:
    warn: no
```

`shell` to allow pipes, `warn: no` to suppress warning.

But if I were you, I'd use `apt_key` + `apt_repository` Ansible modules to create self explaining playbook that also support `check_mode` runs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing clearly how to set `warn:` in shell module. Doc is not clear about that.

Comment: Please note that as of ansible-core 2.13.x  the warn flag is no longer valid syntax and your recipe will fail. Please leave that out.

Answer (score 4):

> Consider using the [`get_url`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html) or [`uri`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html) module rather than running `curl`.

For example:

```
- name: Download Node.js setup script
  get_url: url=https://deb.nodesource.com/setup dest=/opt mode=755
- name: Setup Node.js
  command: /opt/setup
- name: Install Node.js (JavaScript run-time environment)
  apt: name=nodejs state=present
```

Comment: This won't help if the pipe leads to something other than bash

Answer (score 2):

If you only wants to remove the warning message, you can use shell module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#examples) and add the property

```
  args:
    warn: no
```

Below of shell property command, but it's not a good practice ignore warnings, it's better if you consider use the get_url module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html#examples), for example for a Node 10 installation in a Centos 7, you can use:

```
   - name: Download NodeJs script
     get_url:
       url: https://rep.nodesource.com/setup_10.x 
       dest: /opt/nodesetup
       mode: 0755

   - name: Execute setup NodeJs script
     shell: /opt/nodesetup

   - name: Install NodeJs
     yum:
       name: nodejs
       state: present
```

For others versions or OS, yo can change the repo *"https://rep.nodesource.com/setup_10.x"* for example for *"https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x*" and the setup and install commands accord with the SO.