# Cannot run CURL command in Ansible

Tags: macos, curl, ansible, istio

I was trying to download Istio using ansible. There I used the following structure.

```
- name: Download Istio
  command: curl https://istio.io/downloadIstio | sh -
- name: Start minikube
  command: minikube start
```

But when I run the command it returns,

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["curl", "https://istio.io/downloadIstio", "|", "sh", "-"], "delta": "0:00:00.005276", "end": "2019-11-20 11:32:17.749051", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2019-11-20 11:32:17.743775", "stderr": "curl: option -: is unknown\ncurl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information", "stderr_lines": ["curl: option -: is unknown", "curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation of the "command" module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html):

> The command(s) will not be processed through the shell, so variables
>   like $HOME and operations like "<", ">", "|", ";" and "&" will not
>   work. Use the shell module if you need these features.

Instead, use the ["shell" module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html):

```
- name: Download Istio
  shell: curl https://istio.io/downloadIstio | sh -
```

Comment: And besides that, in this simple situation (get a remote content), don't use curl in shell, use the [`get_url`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html) or [`uri`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html) modules

Answer (score 1):

As per ansible [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html) and Zeitounator [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58947800/cannot-run-curl-command-in-ansible/58948860#comment104155171_58948860):

> The command module does not support extended shell syntax like piping and redirects (although shell variables will always work). If your command requires shell-specific syntax, use the shell module instead.

Please consider using [get_url module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html):

> Downloads files from HTTP, HTTPS, or FTP to the remote server. The remote server must have direct access to the remote resource.
>   You can combine this with shell module:

As an example please take a look for this [community example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965199/ansible-wget-then-exec-scripts-get-url-equivalent/36966446#36966446):

```
- name: Download zsh installer
    get_url: url=https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh dest=/tmp/zsh-installer.sh

  - name: Execute the zsh-installer.sh
    shell: /tmp/zsh-installer.sh
```