# Rundeck install plugins with Ansible

Tags: ansible, rundeck, ansible-template

I am using ansible yaml file to create rundeck jobs.
I want to create another job, but there I have to use Http Notification plugin.

I can install plugin manually from rundeck UI.

But is there any option that I can do it from ansible yaml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ansible created new job which runed shell script

```
- name: install Plugins to rundeck
  shell: >
      docker exec rundeck bash -c 'rd plugins install -r=Official -i=5c3a72ab196c -v=1.0.5'
  become: yes
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A playbook that downloads the plugin to the rundeck [libext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36966446/10426011) directory from any rundeck plugin repository (such as [this](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/http-step/releases/download/1.1.3/http-step-1.1.3.jar)) can be used. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36966446/10426011) response.